# How to get data from django Model

Tags: python, django

Ok so I have this Model in django:

```
class Training(models.Model):
      url = models.URLField(max_length=100)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      grouping = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      month = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      overallOrder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      emailSent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

but how do I get the data from those fields?

If I drop to the sqlite shell this is what I get:

```
In [1]: from myapp.models import Training

In [2]: queryset = Training.objects.all()

In [3]: print (queryset)
<QuerySet [<Training: Training object>]>
```

But I want to be able to look at all the data in that database. I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: And more relevantly, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the **str** function:

```
class Training(models.Model):
      url = models.URLField(max_length=100)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      grouping = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      month = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      overallOrder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      emailSent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      def __str__(self):
          return "Training with url %s and title %s"%(self.url, self.title)
```

You can add more fields in the function

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I had seem some examples with def __unicode__ but not __str__. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Django is "lazy" (see [When is a Django QuerySet evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171736/when-is-a-django-queryset-evaluated))

This can be bypassed by forcing a query to be executed e.g. by requesting the nbr of elements, in your example execute:

```
queryset.len()
```